# retrieving dictionary/list from textfile python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, text-files

I want to save a column of values from "coins_info.txt" into a list variable into my program. Here are the contents of "coins_info.txt":

```
Name,ICO,Max,USD_ROI
Bitcoin,0.0,19535.7,N/A
Ethereum,0.0,1389.18,N/A
Ripple,0.0,3.6491,N/A
Bitcoin Cash,0.0,4091.7,N/A
EOS,0.99,21.4637,2068.05%
Litecoin,0.0,366.153,N/A
...
```

I want to get the ICO from every single coin in "coins_info.txt" and save it into a list that looks like this:

```
icos = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.99, 0.0, ...]
```

I tried this code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("coins_info.txt")
icos = df["ICO"].values.tolist()
```

But I got this error for line 4 of my code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2442, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/_libs/index.c:5280)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 154, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/_libs/index.c:5126)
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1210, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:20523)
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1218, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:20477)
KeyError: 'ICO'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 280, in <module>
    init_max_prices("btc.txt", "init")
  File "temp.py", line 212, in init_max_prices
    icos = df["ICO"].values.tolist()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1964, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1971, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1645, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3590, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2444, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/_libs/index.c:5280)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 154, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/_libs/index.c:5126)
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1210, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:20523)
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1218, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:20477)
KeyError: 'ICO'
```

What can I do to fix my code?

Comment: Looks like the df is inside a function and not as simple as the code you posted. Can you confirm if the df there actually has this column called "ICO"? You could just print it before line 212, just before the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the txt file in pandas and convert the ICO column to list, Here is the complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('coins_info.txt', sep=",", header=0)
icos =list(df['ICO']) 
or 
icos = df['ICO'].values.tolist()
```

**Output:**

```
icos = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.99, 0.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code working nice with your sample data:

```
df = pd.read_csv("coins_info.txt")
print (df)
           Name   ICO         Max   USD_ROI
0       Bitcoin  0.00  19535.7000       NaN
1      Ethereum  0.00   1389.1800       NaN
2        Ripple  0.00      3.6491       NaN
3  Bitcoin Cash  0.00   4091.7000       NaN
4           EOS  0.99     21.4637  2068.05%
5      Litecoin  0.00    366.1530       NaN

icos = df["ICO"].values.tolist()
print (icos)
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.99, 0.0]
```

so problem is something else.

---

> KeyError: 'ICO'

means there is no column `ICO`.

First check columns names if some whitespaces or similar:

```
print (df.columns.tolist())
```

Then need:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
```

Or another possible problem is different separator as default `sep=','`.

Then need:

```
df = pd.read_csv("coins_info.txt", sep=';')
icos = df["ICO"].values.tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the ICO from every single coin in "coins_info.txt" and
>   save it into a list that looks like this...

For this task in isolation, Pandas may be overkill. You can use the built-in [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to read your column into a list:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

mystr = StringIO("""Name,ICO,Max,USD_ROI
Bitcoin,0.0,19535.7,N/A
Ethereum,0.0,1389.18,N/A
Ripple,0.0,3.6491,N/A
Bitcoin Cash,0.0,4091.7,N/A
EOS,0.99,21.4637,2068.05%
Litecoin,0.0,366.153,N/A""")

# replace mystr with open('coins_info.txt', 'r')
with mystr as fin:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fin)
    ico_list = [float(row['ICO']) for row in reader]

print(ico_list)

[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.99, 0.0]
```